# Python: Save radio Button tkinter values in an Excel file

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a small interface with Tkinter with 4 radio buttons and each time I click on one of the buttons it will print the value of the button, I've managed to do that!

However, I would like the printed value to be saved in an Excel file for example each time I click on one of the buttons in my tkinter window.

Below is the code I used and the result I got:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

master = Tk()
master.geometry("175x175")
 
# Tkinter string variable
# able to store any string value
v = IntVar(master, "0") #0 pour qu'aucun des boutons soit sélectioné par défaut

# Dictionary to create multiple buttons
values = {"classe 1" : "1",
          "classe 2" : "2",
          "classe 3" : "3",
          "classe 4" : "4"}


def affiche ():
    val = v.get()
    print(val)
    
    data = [
       ['class1', val],
     
       ]


labelValue = tk.Label(master, 
         text="""Choose your class affectation:""",
         justify = tk.LEFT,
         padx = 20).pack()

for (text, value) in values.items():
    Radiobutton(master, text = text, variable = v, command = affiche, 
                value = value).pack(side =TOP, ipady = 5)

# Infinite loop can be terminated by
# keyboard or mouse interrupt
# or by any predefined function (destroy())
mainloop()
```

On the right of the capture below are the values I would like to save in an excel file each time I click.

I got them by clicking respectively on class1, class2, class3 and class4
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rnpwg.png)

I am a beginner, any help is appreciated!

Thank you very much.

Comment: please post your code as formatted text, not as a link

Comment: And please don't post code as images. Images of code are useless.

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit this !

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I just corected it, it's ok?

Comment: You can use module like [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to save the values to an Excel file.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks for the suggestion, but I already used the XlsxWriter module, but I had a problem. By clicking on the buttons I can just save the value of the first button on the 4 buttons. You can have a look at my code below: oops! I don't know how to show you my piece of code as a comment!

Comment: Show the code how you save the value to Excel file.

Comment: I put the piece of code in reply !

Answer (score 0):

I just completed the previous program

```
def affiche ():
    val = v.get()
    print(val)
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Mon fichier.xlsx')   
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("My sheet") 
    data = [
       ['class1', val],
       ['class2', val],
       ['class3', val],
       ['class4', val],
       ]
    
    caption = 'My data.'

    # Set the columns widths.
    worksheet.set_column('B:G', 12)

    # Write the caption.
    worksheet.write('B1', caption)

    # Add a table to the worksheet.
    worksheet.add_table('B4:L4', {'header_row': 0})

    # Table data can also be written separately, as an array or individual cells.
    worksheet.write_row('B4', data[0])
    worksheet.write_row('B5', data[1])
    worksheet.write_row('B6', data[2])
    worksheet.write_row('B7', data[3])
    workbook.close()
```